# How many critical points are there in $(\,x- 1\,)(\,x- 2\,)\,...\,(\,x- 2020\,)$?

Tags: derivatives, discriminant

How many critical points are there in 
$$(\,x- 1\,)(\,x- 2\,)\,...\,(\,x- 2020\,)$$
My observation is

There are $7$ critical points (${\rm C.P}$) in 
$$(\,x- 1\,)(\,x- 2\,)\,...\,(\,x- 8\,)$$
$[\,{\rm C.P},\,x\,]\in (\,1,\,2\,),\,(\,2,\,3\,),\,...\,,(\,7,\,8\,)$

There are $8$ critical points (${\rm C.P}$) in 
$$(\,x- 1\,)(\,x- 2\,)\,...\,(\,x- 9\,)$$
$[\,{\rm C.P},\,x\,]\in (\,1,\,2\,),\,(\,2,\,3\,),\,...\,,(\,7,\,8\,),\,(\,8,\,9\,)$

...

There are $2019$ critical points (${\rm C.P}$) in 
$$(\,x- 1\,)(\,x- 2\,)\,...\,(\,x- 2020\,)$$
$[\,{\rm C.P},\,x\,]\in (\,1,\,2\,),\,(\,2,\,3\,),\,...\,,(\,2017,\,2018\,),\,(\,2018,\,2019\,),\,(\,2019,\,2020\,)$

But I can find the way to use it there, I need to the help! Thanks for all the nice comments and your interests! (I also guess by using discriminant, so I think this may help us!) Good luck everybody! $29$.

Comment: Use Rolle's theorem and fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost done! Note that the function is differentiable everywhere, and that there are $2020$ zeroes. Thus, by [Rolle's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), there are at least $2019$ critical points. Since the derivative of the function is a polynomial of degree $2019,$ then it has at most $2019$ zeroes by the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), meaning that your function has at most $2019$ critical points.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Rolle theorem for each of the intervals you mentioned. You cannot have more than 2020-1=2019 critical points because your derivative is a polynomial of a degree 2020-1=2019